# OracleDataReader not being iterated despite having rows

Tags: c#, oracle11g, odbc, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 19.6.0 to get some data from Oracle 11g 11.2.0.3.0

This code was working fine until yesterday. 223 rows are getting returned by Oracle. But the `while (orclDataReader.Read())` is being skipped, as if there are no rows.

What am I doing wrong? Especially given that this same code has been running fine for at least a week now.

```
using (OracleDataReader orclDataReader = orclCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    _logger.DebugFormat("{0} rows retreived ", orclDataReader.RowSize);
    while (orclDataReader.Read())
    {
        //do something with rows
        //this whole section is being skipped by VS debugger
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the command doesn't issue two selects? one with zero rows, and *then* your data?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes I'm sure that there is only one select in the SQL. The `OracleConnection` object is shared for multiple queries executed 1 by 1. There are no threads or processes involved.

Comment: @theb frankly then, it sounds like maybe the parameters are wrong, such that it is returning zero rows... Can you show any of the command code?

Comment: There is no magic. Take the SQL you use in command, and paste in Sql Developer. Run it and see if there are any rows. or modify `select` part in debug mode. Do `select count(*)` while leaving everything else same. Take command object and copy out of it `ConnectionString` property, see where you actually connecting. Questions like this always end up being problems like *"connected to wrong DB/server"*. The code you posted does not do anything to point to a problem

Comment: @T.S. that's what it was. `OracleDataReader.RowSize` does not give row count! It gives " amount of memory (in bytes) that an OracleDataReader needs to store one row of data for the executed query". Row count probably does not exist in this library. Anyway - bottom line - row count was zero due to logic in the SQL.

Comment: I knew that `RowSize` is not what you thought. But in your code, it didn't matter. Control still was going to `reader.Read`. And this is where you had no rows. Reader never knows ahead how many rows you have because reader reads data as it iterating via `Read` command